# Problems Mounting NFS Shared Drive Using Fstab (Ubuntu - Lucid Linux)

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-10.04, nfs, share, fstab

Currently I have clients hooked up to a server through NFS such that user home folders mount to the clients (if you want more info on that, let me know).

I am trying to set up a shared drive, in which every file and folder can be edited by any user. Therefore, I have this fstab entry:

```
babbage:/home/Shared    /media/shared   nfs     nolock,rw,dmask=027,fmask=137,relatime  0       0
```

I used the information (regarding fmask and dmask) from this forum post

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131

However, whenever I use any form of *mask, the drive does not mount (I know this because when I remove the *mask, the drive mounts, however with incorrect permissions).

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dmask and fmask are only applicable for FAT and NTFS partitions.

In short, there's no simple way which I can think of to do exactly what you are saying while preserving ownership information.  If file ownership information is not important then you could setup the NFS export with the `all_squash` option (assuming you're using Linux for your NFS server):

```
/home/Shared *(rw,all_squash)
```

This would effectively make all file accesses (reads, writes, creates, etc) run as the anonymous user on the NFS server.  `/home/Shared` would need to readable/writable by the anonymous user on your system (probably `nfsnobody` on Linux), either by setting ownership or by setting world rwx permissions.